# react-router Link changing route prior to redux state updates?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-router, frontend

I have 2 pages A and B. There is a link on B that leads to A via a `react-router` `Link`.

B -> click Link to A -> A

B dispatches a redux action on `componentWillUnmount` that updates some state that should be reflected in A. However, although the redux action runs prior to the `componentDidMount` of A, the props are not yet updated when the lifecycle method runs. There is an additional re-render after mounting A that reflects the new redux state, but I want the props on mount.

Is there any simple way around this?

Comment: No, not really. Is the action an asynchronous action in any way?

Comment: @DrewReese no, I set breakpoints and the reducer is hit prior to the componentDidMount in the next component, but it's not until the re-render after the initial mount that the reducer state is reflected in the component.

Comment: Could you update your question to include a [mcve] that includes the redux code (actions and reducers) and the UI code triggering the state updates and navigation effects?

Comment: @DrewReese I have tried and I cannot reproduce it minimally. So I'm hoping someone can point me in the right direction, as I'm at a debugging standstill. The redux action fires and I see the reducer run for the action, but then right after the componentDidMount on the next component runs with the not updated props, and then re-renders with the correct props a split-second after. In the reducer dev tool logs I see LOCATION_CHANGE before the reducer action being applied. In other scenarios it works so I'm not sure where to look. I'll keep debugging though, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

After more research, it seems that it is the expectation that React can choose when to call `componentWillMount` and `componentWillUnmount`, so it is not a correct assumption in the first place.